# CodenameOne scrolling issue with keyboard

Tags: codenameone

When a form is shown that does not fit into the screen, I am able to scroll to the bottom as expected. When I then press one of the fields, the keyboard shows up, and while the keyboard is up, I am able to scroll to the bottom of the screen (once again, as expected), irrelevant of what field I pressed.

**Example Screenshots:**

Scroll to bottom with no keyboard:

[image: Scroll to bottom with no keyboard]

Scroll to bottom with keyboard:

[image: Scroll to bottom with keyboard:]

However, when a form is shown that **does** fit into the screen, The form does not scroll when the keyboard becomes active, hiding fields. 
In this example, I reduced the amount of fields to fit into the screen, and when I press on one of the fields that would not be hidden when the keyboard shows, I am unable to scroll downward to the last field (total of 14 fields):

[image: No scroll]

When I do initially press on a field that would be hidden form the keyboard  (such as the last field), I am once again able to scroll:

[image: Scroll Small]

Is there a way to always ensure scrolling when things are hidden due to keyboard?

The code for this:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        hi.addComponent(getEntry(i + 1));
    }
    hi.show();
}

public Container getEntry(int val) {
    Container c = new Container();
    c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    TextField tf = new TextField() {
        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth(), 70);
        }
    };
    tf.setConstraint(TextField.DECIMAL);
    tf.setText(val + "");
    c.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tf);
    return c;

}
```

The only difference between these 2 tests is the value of `i` so that I have either more fields than what the screen can show or just enough. In my case values `20` and `14` respectively.

This was tested using an Android device.

Comment: This sounds like a misbehavior of the virtual keyboard, it probably tests the `isScrollable()` flag which is true in this case and thus tries to be "smart" about it. Please file an issue on this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this is still an open issue, check here: [Ability to scroll Form/Components while virtual keyboard is showing #361](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone/issues/361)

Comment: That issue is unrelated. In the past every time you started to scroll the keyboard would automatically fold